# return object on Main thread GCD

Tags: iphone, nsarray, grand-central-dispatch

I want to return an array of cached images. See the code. I simply want to return the array I've created, but I can't in the `dispatch_get_main_queue` and I don't know how to alter the code to return the array. I'm sure this is easy, but I struggle with the lower level C / GCD syntax. Thanks.

```
-(NSArray *)returnArray
{

    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"something" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:array.count];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);


    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
       ]
        for(int i=0;i<array.count; i++) {

            NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[array objectAtIndex:i]];

            UIImage *frameImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frameImage.size);
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameImage.size.width, frameImage.size.height);
            [frameImage drawInRect:rect];
            UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            [finalArray addObject:renderedImage];

        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //THIS IS WHAT IM TRYING TO DO, BUT I CANT
            return finalArray;
        });

    });

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `dispatch_async()` when you want to return an array synchronously? That's not going to work.

Comment: goal was to asynchronously run the for loop and return the array when all of the loop is executed. Rather than blocking as it renders each image

Comment: That's it, @KevinBallard is right. You can not return things using async approaches. Maybe you should use the delegate pattern, or passing a completition block.

Comment: @Eric but if you're using `return` then where do you expect the result to go if the caller isn't blocked waiting for the result? Either the actor that performed `[object returnArray]` has to sit and wait for a result or it's moved on and there's no longer anywhere for a `return` to return to.

Comment: Then put the call to that method (`returnArray`) in a `dispatch_async` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this without sacrificing asynchrony. You'll need to create a function that takes that value as an argument, and call it passing finalArray as the argument. So instead of your control flow looking like this (-> indicating "calls" and <- indicating "returns"):

```
returnArray -> 
    async (private queue) -> 
        sync (main queue) <-
    ... <-
returnArray <-
```

It will look like this:

```
returnArray -> 
    async (private queue) -> 
        sync (main queue) ->
            useArray (array)
```

Comment: so useArray is a method somewhere else that takes my final created array? That makes sense.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Remember though, that since it's async, you aren't in control of when it will get called relative to other things going on in your program.